# TSQL -- find records in table with multiples in one column, and at least one specific occurrence of a value in another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, having-clause

**TSQL -- find records in table with multiples in one column, and at least one specific occurrence of a value in another column**

If I have:
ourDB.dbo.ourTable with col1 and col2 and col 3

I want to find occurrences such that
 * A value of col1 occurs multiple times
 * at least one instance of col2 = 'Val1' at least once.

TSQL -- find specific occurrence in table

So one would start with:

```
Select col1, col2, col3
FROM ourDB.dbo.ourTable
having count(col1) > 1
WHERE
(col2 = 'Val1')
Group by col1, col2, col3
Order by col1, col2, col3
```

This would find where col2 always occurs with 'Val1', but how is this generalized to Col2 having 'Val1' at least once ?

Comment: Still not sure why there is a down vote here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must `GROUP BY col1` only and with conditional aggregation you get all the `col1` values you need:

```
SELECT * FROM ourDB.dbo.ourTable
WHERE col1 IN (
  SELECT col1
  FROM ourDB.dbo.ourTable
  GROUP BY col1
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 'Val1' THEN 1 END) > 0
)
ORDER BY col1, col2, col3
```

If you want only the rows with `col2 = 'Val1'`:

```
SELECT * FROM ourDB.dbo.ourTable
WHERE
  col2 = 'Val1'
  AND 
  col1 IN (
    SELECT col1
    FROM ourDB.dbo.ourTable
    GROUP BY col1
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 'Val1' THEN 1 END) > 0
  )
  ORDER BY col1, col3
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method below, originally from a colleague, I modified it some.
NOTE:  Not necessarily better than other (accepted) answer, just different approach.

```
 -- GENERIC_JOIN_WITH_SPECIFIC_COUNTS_Q_v_0.sql
    USE [ourDB]
    SELECT COUNT( distinct titleid)  -- also could use COUNT(*)  
    from ourTable
    
    WHERE 
    (
        (1 < 
          (
            select count( col1) 
            from ourTable
            GROUP BY col1
            HAVING (count(col1 > 1) 
            -- more than one col1 occurence
            )
         )
    
        AND 
        (0 < 
          (
            select count(*) from ourTable
            WHERE( col2 = 'Val1' ) 
            -- at least one occurence of col2 having 'Val1'
          )
         )
    )
```